# How to create a 2 dimensional permutation structure in C#

Tags: c#, list, statistics, permutation

I have the following

- 1000 people
- 50 objects

Some "rules"

- Each person must have *exactly* `1` object
- All people can have the same object (people can share an object)
- Not all objects have to be used

I want to chart out the permutations - How would I go about generating this structure in say C#?

I've currently just been randomly selecting an object for a person and remembering what I selected so I don't select it again in the next iteration - not useful I know.

Comment: can one person have multiple objects?

Comment: no, they can only have 1 object. They can't have 0 objects.

Comment: Please add this point in your question as its very important point, and also you can look for recursion.

Comment: Note that your end goal is impossible. You cannot store that much data anywhere on earth. In comparaison the total size of the internet is estimated to hit 175 zettabytes by 2025 and your data would require about (2.2 x 10^91) times that space to store it.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I had a feeling there were too many permutations to store and reference. I will adapt the approach to enumerate and break out after so many iterations/time elapsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having `100` people and `50` objects you are going to have

```
100 ^ 50 = 1e100  # `^` means raising into power
```

*googol* solutions; it's by far more than elementary particles in the visible part of the Universe. That's why let not materialize the solution into any collection (2d array etc. - we are not looking for `OutOfMemoryException`) but enumerate them; at least you can *stop enumerating* whenever you want:

**Code:**

```
using System.Linq;
...
private static IEnumerable<(K key, V value)[]> MySampling<K, V>(IEnumerable<K> keys, 
                                                                IEnumerable<V> values) {
  if (keys is null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(keys));
  if (values is null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(values));

  IReadOnlyList<K> keysList = keys is IReadOnlyList<K> keysFound 
    ? keysFound : keys.ToList();
  IReadOnlyList<V> valuesList = values is IReadOnlyList<V> valuesFound 
    ? valuesFound : values.ToList();

  if (keysList.Count <= 0 || valuesList.Count <= 0)
    yield break;

  int[] indexes = new int[keysList.Count];

  do {
    yield return Enumerable
      .Range(0, keysList.Count)
      .Select(i => (key: keysList[i], value: valuesList[indexes[i]]))
      .ToArray();

    for (int i = indexes.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
      if (++indexes[i] == valuesList.Count)
        indexes[i] = 0;
      else
        break;
  } 
  while (indexes.Any(index => index != 0));
}
```

**Demo:**

```
char[] people = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' };
int[] objects = { 1, 2, 3 };

var result = MySampling(people, objects);

var report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
  .Select(line => string.Join(" ", line.Select(item => $"({item.key} : {item.value})"))));

Console.Write(report);
```

**Output:**

```
(A : 1) (B : 1) (C : 1) (D : 1) # all people - A, B, C, D - chose 1st object
(A : 1) (B : 1) (C : 1) (D : 2) # people A, B, C chose 1st, D chose 2nd object
(A : 1) (B : 1) (C : 1) (D : 3)
(A : 1) (B : 1) (C : 2) (D : 1)
(A : 1) (B : 1) (C : 2) (D : 2)
(A : 1) (B : 1) (C : 2) (D : 3)
(A : 1) (B : 1) (C : 3) (D : 1)
(A : 1) (B : 1) (C : 3) (D : 2)
(A : 1) (B : 1) (C : 3) (D : 3)
(A : 1) (B : 2) (C : 1) (D : 1)
(A : 1) (B : 2) (C : 1) (D : 2)
(A : 1) (B : 2) (C : 1) (D : 3)
(A : 1) (B : 2) (C : 2) (D : 1)
(A : 1) (B : 2) (C : 2) (D : 2)
(A : 1) (B : 2) (C : 2) (D : 3)
(A : 1) (B : 2) (C : 3) (D : 1)
(A : 1) (B : 2) (C : 3) (D : 2)
(A : 1) (B : 2) (C : 3) (D : 3)
(A : 1) (B : 3) (C : 1) (D : 1)
(A : 1) (B : 3) (C : 1) (D : 2)
(A : 1) (B : 3) (C : 1) (D : 3)
(A : 1) (B : 3) (C : 2) (D : 1)
(A : 1) (B : 3) (C : 2) (D : 2)
(A : 1) (B : 3) (C : 2) (D : 3)
(A : 1) (B : 3) (C : 3) (D : 1)
(A : 1) (B : 3) (C : 3) (D : 2)
(A : 1) (B : 3) (C : 3) (D : 3)
(A : 2) (B : 1) (C : 1) (D : 1)
(A : 2) (B : 1) (C : 1) (D : 2)
(A : 2) (B : 1) (C : 1) (D : 3)
(A : 2) (B : 1) (C : 2) (D : 1)
(A : 2) (B : 1) (C : 2) (D : 2)
(A : 2) (B : 1) (C : 2) (D : 3)
(A : 2) (B : 1) (C : 3) (D : 1)
(A : 2) (B : 1) (C : 3) (D : 2)
(A : 2) (B : 1) (C : 3) (D : 3)
(A : 2) (B : 2) (C : 1) (D : 1)
(A : 2) (B : 2) (C : 1) (D : 2)
(A : 2) (B : 2) (C : 1) (D : 3)
(A : 2) (B : 2) (C : 2) (D : 1)
(A : 2) (B : 2) (C : 2) (D : 2)
(A : 2) (B : 2) (C : 2) (D : 3)
(A : 2) (B : 2) (C : 3) (D : 1)
(A : 2) (B : 2) (C : 3) (D : 2)
(A : 2) (B : 2) (C : 3) (D : 3)
(A : 2) (B : 3) (C : 1) (D : 1)
(A : 2) (B : 3) (C : 1) (D : 2)
(A : 2) (B : 3) (C : 1) (D : 3)
(A : 2) (B : 3) (C : 2) (D : 1)
(A : 2) (B : 3) (C : 2) (D : 2)
(A : 2) (B : 3) (C : 2) (D : 3)
(A : 2) (B : 3) (C : 3) (D : 1)
(A : 2) (B : 3) (C : 3) (D : 2)
(A : 2) (B : 3) (C : 3) (D : 3)
(A : 3) (B : 1) (C : 1) (D : 1)
(A : 3) (B : 1) (C : 1) (D : 2)
(A : 3) (B : 1) (C : 1) (D : 3)
(A : 3) (B : 1) (C : 2) (D : 1)
(A : 3) (B : 1) (C : 2) (D : 2)
(A : 3) (B : 1) (C : 2) (D : 3)
(A : 3) (B : 1) (C : 3) (D : 1)
(A : 3) (B : 1) (C : 3) (D : 2)
(A : 3) (B : 1) (C : 3) (D : 3)
(A : 3) (B : 2) (C : 1) (D : 1)
(A : 3) (B : 2) (C : 1) (D : 2)
(A : 3) (B : 2) (C : 1) (D : 3)
(A : 3) (B : 2) (C : 2) (D : 1)
(A : 3) (B : 2) (C : 2) (D : 2)
(A : 3) (B : 2) (C : 2) (D : 3)
(A : 3) (B : 2) (C : 3) (D : 1)
(A : 3) (B : 2) (C : 3) (D : 2)
(A : 3) (B : 2) (C : 3) (D : 3)
(A : 3) (B : 3) (C : 1) (D : 1)
(A : 3) (B : 3) (C : 1) (D : 2)
(A : 3) (B : 3) (C : 1) (D : 3)
(A : 3) (B : 3) (C : 2) (D : 1)
(A : 3) (B : 3) (C : 2) (D : 2)
(A : 3) (B : 3) (C : 2) (D : 3)
(A : 3) (B : 3) (C : 3) (D : 1)
(A : 3) (B : 3) (C : 3) (D : 2)
(A : 3) (B : 3) (C : 3) (D : 3)
```